# what is the purpose of the SQLDataAdapter RowUpdating event

Tags: events, ado.net, sqldataadapter

What is the purpose of the RowUpdating event of the SQL Data Adapter? According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdating.aspx), it cannot be used to "intercept" the update process and prevent the update command from being executed:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdating.aspx

The command gets executed in any case. Since this event is not well suited to client-side data-validation, what is a good (best practices) use of the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d1wk41s.aspx):

> You can use RowUpdating to modify update behavior before it happens,
>   to provide additional handling when an update will occur, to retain a
>   reference to an updated row, to cancel the current update and schedule
>   it for a batch process to be processed later, and so on. RowUpdated is
>   useful for responding to errors and exceptions that occur during the
>   update. You can add error information to the DataSet, as well as retry
>   logic, and so on.

For instance, to cancel the current row's update, you could use the [`SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlrowupdatingeventargs.aspx) param:

```
private void DaRowUpdating(Object sender, SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs e) {
    e.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;
    e.Row.RejectChanges();
}
```